# Make a delegate method in custom class overridable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

So I have a custom class, and I've defined a delegate method for it. Here's a simplified example:

```
protocol MyDelegate {
    func myDelegateMethod()
}

class Myclass (){
    //other stuff
    func myDelegateMethod(){
        //some operation
    }
}
```

And I would like to override this method from another class. I used

```
override func myDelegateMethod(){
}
```

But I got this error

> Method does not override any method from its superclass

I understand that this is saying that the super class didn't implement this method so I don't need to use the `override` keyword. But in my case I do have `myDelegateMethod` in the super class `MyClass`, and I do want to override it.

So how can I make this function overridable?

Edit:

If you want to see the actual code, here's [the gist](https://gist.github.com/hkalexling/ab0f2a239c0f0903a673)

Comment: post your subclass code. we can't help you if you don't post the code that is actually giving the problem

Comment: @RMenke i've edited the question and added a link to the gist

Comment: @RMenke oops, sorry. I've added the subclass. The method I am trying to override is `awImageViewDidLongPress()`

Comment: it conforms to a delegate, it is not a subclass. No override needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
protocol MyDelegate {
    func myDelegateMethod()
}
```

---

This is an `extension` to the `protocol`. By giving the `func` and empty `block` it is now an `optional func`. You can put something in the function and make that the default implementation.

```
extension MyDelegate {

    func myDelegateMethod() { } // just a default

}
```

This now compiles:

```
class Myclass : MyDelegate {

}
```

---

This is a class without inheritance or conformance. It has a method with the same name as the delegate but the two are completely unrelated. This is confusing.

```
class Myclass {
    //other stuff
    func myDelegateMethod() {
        //some operation
    }
}
```

---

This is a class conforming to a protocol, no `override` is needed.

```
class Myclass : MyDelegate {
    //other stuff
    func myDelegateMethod(){
        //some operation
    }
}
```

This is a subclass, it needs `override` if you want the function to have a different body.

```
class MySubClass : Myclass {

    override func myDelegateMethod() {
        // you're not my supervisor
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank. i've edited the question and added a link to the gist

Comment: Ah i see. Then in my case, is there a way to implement only one of the delegate methods in the second class?

Comment: @AlexLing ?? please elaborate. I have no idea what the functions do. I looked at your structure, since that is what the question is about.

Comment: `MyClass` conforms to the protocol, and both of the two delegate methods have to be used in `MyClass`. If I only use one of them Xcode will give me an error saying that `MyClass` can't conform to that delegate. So is it possible to use only one of them?

Comment: @AlexLing happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for creating Custom Delegate. So below there are two viewController (viewController1 and viewController2). In this viewController1 will send data to viewController2 using custom delegate:-

**//AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var window: UIWindow?
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        //Created Instance of both view controller
        let vwController1 = ViewController1()
        let vwController2 = ViewController2()
        //Now set Viewcontroller1 to delegate of Viewcontroller2
        vwController1.delegate = vwController2
        vwController1.test()
        return true
    }
```

**//ViewController1.swift**

```
import UIKit
protocol customDelegate{
    //Created Custom Delegate method
    func sendData(dataValue: String) -> String
}
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    var delegate : customDelegate?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    //Below function will send data to ViewController2 using custom delegate
    func test () {
        delegate?.sendData("test")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

//ViewController2.swift

```
import UIKit
class ViewController2: UIViewController,customDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    //Below is the custom delegate method which will invoke by Viewcontroller1 with sending data
    func sendData(dataValue: String) -> String {
        print("\(dataValue) recieved")
        return dataValue
    }
}
```